# heap corruption after deleting dynamic array

Tags: c++, error-handling, runtime-error, heap-corruption

I know that this question was asked many times but I couldn't find the solution for my error
I am trying to make a program to check whether the matrix given is symmetric or not the user enters the number of test cases then the size  then the matrix and the output is whether it's symmetric or not 
the program works fine until I try a size more than 3 it breaks with this error and when debugging it seems that it breaks at  delete[]arrL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int n(char s)
{
    switch (s)
    {
    case '0':
        return 0;
    case '1':
        return 1;
    case '2':
        return 2;
    case '3':
        return 3;
    case '4':
        return 4;
    case '5':
        return 5;
    case '6':
        return 6;
    case '7':
        return 7;
    case '8':
        return 8;
    case '9':
        return 9;
    }
}
int getnumber(string a)
{
    string num = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(a[i]))
            num += a[i];
    }
    if (num.size() == 1)
    {
        return n(num[0]);
    }
    if (num.size() == 2)
    {
        return (n(num[0]) * 10) + (n(num[1]));
    }

    if (num.size() == 3)
    {
        return (n(num[0]) * 100) + (n(num[1]) * 10) + (n(num[2]));
    }
}
bool matrix2(long  int**p, int r)
{

    int c = 0, u = 0, ss = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            if (p[i][j]<0)
                return false;
        }
    }
    long  int*arrL = new long  int[r];
    long  int*arrR = new long  int[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            arrL[c++] = p[i][j];
            ss++;
        }
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < r; j++)
        {
            arrR[u++] = p[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ss; i++)
    {
        int q = ss - i - 1;
        long  int a = arrR[i];
        long  int b = arrL[q];
        if (!(a == b))
        {
            delete[]arrL;
            delete[]arrR;
            return false;
        }
        }


    delete[]arrL;
    delete[]arrR;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for (int num = 0; num < t;num++)
    {

        int yy = num + 1;
        string dimension;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, dimension);
        int r = getnumber(dimension);
        long  int**p = new  long int*[r];
        for (int w = 0; w < r; w++){
            p[w] = new  long int[r];
        }
        for (int w = 0; w < r; w++)
        {
            for (int ww = 0; ww < r; ww++)
            {
                cin >> p[w][ww];
            }
        }
    bool result = matrix2(p, r);
        if (result)
        {
            cout << "Test #" << yy << ": Symmetric." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Test #" << yy << ": Non-symmetric." << endl;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            delete[]p[i];
        }
        delete[] p;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `int n(char s) {return s-'0';}` better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arrL and arrR are allocated of size r, but then
arrL[c++] = p[i][j];
is executed more than r times, so c exceeds r, so you've corrupted your heap.